# I cannot add PATH to PATH file on mac

Tags: postgresql, terminal, bash

Here are my .bash_profile and .profile files:

BASH PROFILE

```
# Set architecture flags
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"

export PATH="$HOME/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:$PATH"

#Virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/Devaus/Envs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devaus/Envs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session         *as a function*
```

PROFILE

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

echo $PATH

```
/Users/User/Devaus/Envs/wsd/bin:/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-        2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.1.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/User/.rvm/bin
```

The question is why `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin` won't be added to PATH? My goal is to use `psql`etc commands stated in here http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html

Comment: 1. Does the `rmv` script initialize the `PATH` variable? 2. Include in your bash_profile a `flag`, for example, `touch /tmp/my_file` and check the /tmp/my_file has been created.

Comment: Oh, I feel stupid. I just had to source the bash file after the edit. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Bash does not automatically read `.profile` if you have a `.bash_profile`.  Usually this is set up with `.bash_profile` explicitly loading `.profile` but you don't seem to have that.  Maybe add this to the beginning of your `.bash_profile`:

```
test -e ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
```

Or alternatively put those things in your `.bash_profile` instead; but then if you need some or all of these settings with `/bin/sh` you can't do that.  It is usually a better arrangement to only have specifically Bash-only code in your `.bash_profile` and keep your `.profile` portable to classic Bourne shell (which does not allow `export` before a variable assignment; so you have syntax error where

```
export variable=value
```

should be

```
variable=value
export variable
```

instead for portability.)

Incidentally, you only have to `export` once (and`PATH` should already be exported by the time Bash runs your personal login files, anyway).